# Visual Studio Code automatically removes the latest empty lines when I'm changing windows/tabs. How to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example the code is this:

```
void main() {
  String msg = "Hi";

  Function say = () {
    msg = "Hello";
    print(msg);
  };
  
  
}
```

Every time I change tabs and come back to VSCode, the code would end up looking like this

```
void main() {
  String msg = "Hi";

  Function say = () {
    msg = "Hello";
    print(msg);
  };
}
```

As you can see, it automatically deleted the empty line that I wanted to use after researching stuff on the other windows. Is there any VSCode setting to change this?

Comment: What language is this? It looks like you're using an auto-formatter that (a) removes the blank lines, and (b) is run when you switch tabs.

Comment: This is the Dart language. Does VSCode have a built-in auto-formatter?

Comment: Do you have any Dart extensions installed? The `dart-code.dart-code` extension has format-on-save and format-on-type support.

Comment: (with that said, I can't get the dart formatter to work at all, so I can't try to reproduce your problem...)